# Display different <h1> text on interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, setinterval

I would like to take an array of quotes and display a different qoute on my page every 6 seconds.

I have tried using a javascript function that loops through the array and fades in the new qoute. but I keep getting the error `qoutes` is not defined. I have tried moving the array into the function and into the `$(document).ready()` function and still got the same error.

Below is my app.js code:

```
var quotes = [
"Don't Limit Your Challenges, Challenge Your Limits.",
"If the doors of perception were cleansed every thing would appear to man as it is, Infinite.",
"The Power of Imaginiation Makes Us Infinite",
"The finite mind tries to limit the infinite.",
"The Only Limits In Our Life Are Those We Impose on Ourselves."
 ];


var quoteTimer = function(){

for(var i = 0; i< qoutes.length; i++){
    $('.container').find('h1').fadeIn().text(qoutes[i]);

}
}


$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(quoteTimer, 6000);
});
```

Comment: notice that you declared the array `quotes` but then you are trying to loop an array called `qoutes` (they are not the same) - fix the typo first and try again if that does not help - having said that, you are printing all quotes inside the loop every time the function is invoked.

Comment: Check spelling of quotes. in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your time delay and this should do the trick

**Update: added fading**

**Update2: removed placeholder, added comments**

```js
var quotes = [
  "Don't Limit Your Challenges, Challenge Your Limits.",
  "If the doors of perception were cleansed every thing would appear to man as it is, Infinite.",
  "The Power of Imaginiation Makes Us Infinite",
  "The finite mind tries to limit the infinite.",
  "The Only Limits In Our Life Are Those We Impose on Ourselves."
];

// variable to keep track of last quote displayed
var i = 0;

// displays the next quote in the array
var quoteTimer = function() {
  
  // if at end of array, reset
  if (i >= quotes.length) {
    i = 0;
  }

  // fade out previous quote, 
  // while hidden, change the text to the next quote on the array
  $('h1').fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).text(quotes[i]);
  });
  
  // display the quote
  $('h1').fadeIn();

  // increment counter by one
  i++;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').text(quotes[i++]); // initialize with first quote
  setInterval(quoteTimer, 6000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It appears my approach was far off from what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Not very far, just a tad off with the looping but almost there.. Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

2 things:

First of all you have a typo in this line (**qoutes** instead of **quotes**)

```
for(var i = 0; i< qoutes.length; i++){
    $('.container').find('h1').fadeIn().text(qoutes[i]);
}
```

Second, the above code does not do what you think it does, it will quickly cycle through all quotes every 6 seconds, and display the last quote

Try something like the below, which will constantly pick a new random quote from the list.

```
  var quotes = [
    "Don't Limit Your Challenges, Challenge Your Limits.",
    "If the doors of perception were cleansed every thing would appear to man as it is, Infinite.",
    "The Power of Imaginiation Makes Us Infinite",
    "The finite mind tries to limit the infinite.",
    "The Only Limits In Our Life Are Those We Impose on Ourselves."
     ];


    var quoteTimer = function(){
      //pick a random quote
      var quote = getRandomInt(0,4)
      //display it
      $('.container').find('h1').fadeIn().text(quotes[quote]);
    }

    //function to pick a random integer.
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
       setInterval(quoteTimer, 6000);
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rb93qc70/1/)

Comment: This is true, the answer by @ochi shows this solution, more options for the original poster :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var quotes = [
"Don't Limit Your Challenges, Challenge Your Limits.",
"If the doors of perception were cleansed every thing would appear to man as it is, Infinite.",
"The Power of Imaginiation Makes Us Infinite",
"The finite mind tries to limit the infinite.",
"The Only Limits In Our Life Are Those We Impose on Ourselves."
 ];


var quoteTimer = function(){
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    //console.log(quotes[num]);
    $('.container').find('h1').fadeIn().text(quotes[num]);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(quoteTimer, 6000);
});
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but try to add some more explanation in order to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

... HTML ...

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>initial text</h1>
</div>
```

... js ...

```
// define quotes array
var quotes = [
  "Don't Limit Your Challenges, Challenge Your Limits.",
  "If the doors of perception were cleansed every thing would appear to man as it is, Infinite.",
  "The Power of Imaginiation Makes Us Infinite",
  "The finite mind tries to limit the infinite.",
  "The Only Limits In Our Life Are Those We Impose on Ourselves."
];

// initialise current quote index
var quoteIndex = 0;

// set target element
var $target = $('.container').find('h1');

// create timer function
var quoteTimer = function() {
  // set target text to current quote
  $target.fadeIn().text(quotes[quoteIndex]);
  // increment the current index, or reset to 0 if on the last quote
  quoteIndex = quoteIndex < quotes.length - 1 ? quoteIndex + 1 : 0;
}

// fire it up..!
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(quoteTimer, 6000);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zpj1jjxe/1/

Answer (score 2):

Correct the typo`qoutes`, it should be `quotes`

`setInterval` will execute callback after specified duration and will continue so..You may have to invoke the handler(`setInterval callback function`) initially.

To achieve `fadeOut` effect, elements must be in `invisible` state.. Use `.hide()` before `fadeIn()`

Try this:

```js
var quotes = [
  "Don't Limit Your Challenges, Challenge Your Limits.",
  "If the doors of perception were cleansed every thing would appear to man as it is, Infinite.",
  "The Power of Imaginiation Makes Us Infinite",
  "The finite mind tries to limit the infinite.",
  "The Only Limits In Our Life Are Those We Impose on Ourselves."
];
var i = 0;
var elem = $('.container').find('h1');
var quoteTimer = function() {
  elem.hide().fadeIn(1000).text(quotes[i]);
  i = ++i % quotes.length;
}
quoteTimer();
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(quoteTimer, 6000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/0m4hgwu0/)